# ajax request to a linux server sometimes returns me the answer, sometimes returns me error 500

Tags: python, flask, centos, gunicorn

I have a python application with gunicorn and flask on a centos machine. I access the application from another machine in the following way:

```
http://host:port/nameOfFunction?path=https://site/directory1/directory2/directory3/file.pdf
```

The path is correct, because it works. When i enter the same path multiple times, sometimes it works, others, don't.

I am using gunicorn (with the follow command):

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 start:app
```

to start my application. When the answer returns, the screen showing gunicorn prints some piece of code that i put to see some informations.
When it returns me error 500, the code from start isn't printed at all.

I dont have a clue what is the cause of this.

the beginning of the code is:

```
@app.route("/call", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def call():
   print '\n============================BEGINS======================\n'

   path =request.args.get('path')
   newPath = path.rsplit('/',1)[1]
   directoriesRoot(root)
   directoriesRoot(pdfs)

   parameters = ["curl", path.replace(' ','%20'), '--output',pdfs+newPath]

   p = subprocess.Popen(parameters, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   output, err = p.communicate()

  if err:
    return 'ERROR'

   person= functionSecundaryWithNoImportance([newPath])
   return jsonify(person)
```

Someone has some clue or already pass for a similar problem?

Comment: Have you had a look in the http error logs? `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: httpd error logs? No, i dont. I will look for this file.

Comment: I found this:   " [Tue Apr 17 16:10:59.868439 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 51701] [client 168.235.93.142:48078] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/python/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive."

Comment: The directory /var/www/html/python/ is the directory that my code runs! I will try to dig more into this file! thanks.

Comment: One question, why httpd? I am using gunicorn, not apache. I have a vm on the machine i send the resquest, and this machine didnt have httpd. (and to send the same request to the vm where i have the copy of the code works fine every single time).

Comment: It was just a hunch based on most linux systems. That error you posted sounds like something in the config file for the webserver, or maybe you have a `.htaccess` file somewhere. You should edit your question with any updates rather than putting them in comments for people to have to dig through.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works. I am going to post the solution now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of user3788685, i found out that my python application was on port 8080 (and probably one of apache's default ports were 8080) so it conflicts. Sometimes it directs to python, others to apache. So i changed the port for my python application to 1234:

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:1234 start:app
```

and now works as a charm!